# How to organize my tables in DataBase?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm starting a new personal project, and I'm stuck with something I can't deal with. I'll explain you with an example.

On my website (PHP with CodeIgniter framework), I got users. Every users should have his own list of predefined items (several hundreds of items, all available for all users). When an user register, he can see the list, but with a "not earned" mention on it. With time, he'll earn items, and when showing the list, the items he collected should have the "earned" mention. I think that I (obviously) need an User table, and an Items table. But I have not a clue about how can I link the tables to make each user have his own, personal item list, depending of himself and not of other users.

I think I can deal with the code, but I really don't know how to organize my database. If someone can give me a few hints about this, it would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You need three tables: `users`, `items` and `user_items`. `user_items` table contains `user_id` and `item_id` columns so you can get user earned items with query `user_items` table.

For example, get items of user whom id is 7:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name FROM items JOIN user_items ON items.id = user_items.item_id WHERE user_items.user_id = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking about is **Many to Many relation**, which requires an additional table that links Users and Items

like `users_items_earned` with fields `user_id` and `item_id`

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be something like this

```
users
-----
id | name | etc
----------------

items
------
id | etc
---------

user_items
----------
id | user_id | item_id
-----------------------
```

you can add an additional table for the items a user has earned

```
earned_user_items
------------------
id  |   user_id |   item_id
```